# Android getSerializable()

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am passing an ArrayList of Items from one activity to another using a bundle. I am not getting any errors, but the Items do not display in my second activity. Am I implementing the getSerializable() and putSerializable() correctly?

Here is a snippet from my first Activity

ListArray Declared

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Where the items are put into a bundle

```
 Intent ListIntent = new Intent(home.this, SectionListExampleActivity.class);
 Bundle loadInfo = new Bundle();
 loadInfo.putSerializable("items", items);
 ListIntent.putExtras(loadInfo);
```

Second Activity

```
Bundle loadInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
    items = (ArrayList<Item>) loadInfo.getSerializable("items");
```

I have implemented Serializable in both activities. I have ensured that the ArrayList does get populated in the first activity

Comment: Have you ensured that your second view really can visualize the items if you add some static data?

Comment: Yes they can be viewed. When I get the information needed for the items in the second activity there is no problem.

Comment: You don't have to make your Activities Serializable for that...

Comment: Is your "Item" serializable? also in your second activity have you checked whether the size of items is correct? also try printing the values of the first item.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: have you tried to serialize an array of Item (Item[]) instead of ArrayList. I am not shure if ArrayList is serializable.

```
loadInfo.putSerializable("items", items.toArray());

Bundle loadInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
items = (Item[]) loadInfo.getSerializable("items");
```

Comment: problem was fixed by having the Item interface extend Serializable

Answer (score 1):

What is `Item`..? is it Serializable... if not make `Serializable`

Comment: Item is a custom interface, can you make an interface Serializable?

Comment: @sandy isn't it better to clarify the doubts first through comments and then post answer?

Answer (score 1):

Item class :

```
public class Item implements Serializable
```

In first Activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("items", items);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In Second Activity (Activity2):

```
ArrayList<Item> items = (ArrayList<Item>) getIntent().getExtras()
                .getSerializable("items");
```